# Controlling website input values with Joysticks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, joystick

I am making a controller for a Drone in html, it is posting to an arduino API witch transmits the values to the drone. But I am curious about if you can bind some  to joysticks, I have 2 thrustmaster t.16000 witch I would like to control the sliders on the website to make an emersive flight. Is it possible? Here is my website code where I want to control the sliders:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    #controllerForm {
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        justify-content:space-between;
        padding:10em 0;
    }

    .throttleSlider, .pSlider {
        -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    }
    
    .rpSlider, .yThrottleSlider {
        width:50%;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column-reverse;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;

    }
</style>
<body>
<form id="controllerForm" method="post" action="http://10.0.0.161/drone">
    <div class="yThrottleSlider">
        <input class="yslider" type="range" min="-180" max="180" value="0" for="yaw" name="yaw">
        <input class="throttleSlider" type="range" min="1" max="2000" value="1000" for="throttle" name="throttle">
    </div>

    <div class="rpSlider">
        <input class="rSlider" type="range" min="-45" max="45" value="0" for="roll" name="roll">
        <input class="pSlider" type="range" min="-45" max="45" value="0" for="pitch" name="pitch">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit">asd</button>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#controllerForm');

    frm.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });

</script>
</html>
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    var target = document.getElementById("xSlider");

    target.value = joystick.value;
}, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance

Best regards Max

Comment: Relevant?  [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API)

Comment: Yes, thank you! But I am having troubles just updating those inputs... I will update if I accomplish it

Comment: Is there an easy way with this to just take the value of the joystick? I cannot find where in this API I can just grab the value and set the value for the input.